# Term for mentioning X by saying "I will not say X"

Tags: terminology, rhetoric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of the phrase “not to mention …”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-not-to-mention)
>   [Is there a name for “I don't mean to…, but” phrases?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40176/is-there-a-name-for-i-dont-mean-to-but-phrases)

Is there a term for the rhetorical device of making a statement by disguising it in the context of saying that you will not in fact make such a statement? I'm thinking of a politician announcing "I will not stoop to calling my opponent an adulterer" and, in effect, doing exactly that.

Comment: doublespeak? ie: deliberately phrasing something so that it has the opposite meaning that it appears to have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Apophasis** is exactly what you seek. To borrow the definition from Chambers, it means "effectively saying something by stating that you will not mention it."

It is a commonly-used word in theology: a description of God is apophatic when He is described using what He is not.

*EDIT* (adding another answer after FumbleFingers' comment) - **Paralipsis**. Once again borrowing Chambers definition, "A rhetorical figure by which one fixes attention on a subject by pretending to neglect it, as in ‘I will not speak of his generosity’, etc." I concur with FF that this is a better fit than **Apophasis** for OP's question.

Comment: I remember the example of apophasis when I was studying Latin in high school: Cicero's "I am not going to mention the slaughter of the citizens." Also, this is the mechanism used in some jokes/insults, for example, the Russian insult, "You house burn down and you and your family all perish in the blaze, God forbid!"

Comment: @Hexagon Tiling: I don't know how old you are, but I note that Chambers '83 didn't even list *apophasis* - just *apophatic*, which I think is almost always used in the "religious" context. Latest 12th Edition does have it as Shyam says, so I won't downvote the answer, but I don't like it much. The word has too many unwanted connotations, whereas *paralipsis* has been around with far more exactly this sense for a long time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You're right. I was referring to the concept, not the term. What I remember from my Latin study guide is something like "praeterito paralipsis: emphasizing something by the pretence of omitting it". You win the Sherlock Holmes award for today.